# GUI text created during runtime is not visible

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am using the DebugConsole script to show the debug output on screen.It works perfectly but appears at the top left corner. I want it to appear inside a panel where I have created a window and a GUI text element and the script gives this option as well. I see the gui text formed as an element in the project console, but is not visible.

1. I do have a GUI layer
2. My gui text element is the direct child of a canvas
3. Camera is set to screen space overlay. I tried worldspace , still not visible.

My code:

```
namespace OctopartApi
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using RestSharp;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Net;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    public  class KeywordSearch1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public InputField mainInputField;
        public Canvas can;
        public Text infoText;
        public float x, y;
        void Start () {
            mainInputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate {LockInput(mainInputField); });

        }
        void LockInput(InputField input)
        {
            ExecuteSearch (input.text);

        }
        public  void ExecuteSearch(string inp)
        {
            // -- your search query --
            string query = inp;

            string octopartUrlBase = "http://octopart.com/api/v3";
            string octopartUrlEndpoint = "parts/search";
            string apiKey = "57af648b";

            // Create the search request

            var client = new RestClient(octopartUrlBase);
            var req = new RestRequest(octopartUrlEndpoint, Method.GET)
                        .AddParameter("apikey", apiKey)
                        .AddParameter("q", query)
                        .AddParameter("start", "0")
                        .AddParameter("limit", "10");
            var resp = client.Execute(req);
            string octojson = resp.Content;
            RootOb rr = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootOb> (octojson);
            string hhts = (rr.hits).ToString();
            hhts = hhts + rr.user_currency;
            infoText.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Overflow;
            infoText.verticalOverflow = VerticalWrapMode.Overflow;
            infoText.text = hhts;

        //  sendR (inp);
            // Perform the search and obtain results

            /*  var resp = client.Execute(req);
           var search_response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resp.Content);
            Console.WriteLine (search_response);
            // Print the number of hits and results
            Console.WriteLine("Number of hits: " + search_response["hits"]);
            Debug.Log(search_response ["hits"]+"OCTO");
            foreach (var result in search_response["results"])
            {
                var part = result["item"];
                Debug.Log(part["brand"]["name"] + "OCTO" + part["mpn"]+part["octopart_url"]);

                DebugConsole.Log (part ["brand"] ["name"] + "-- " + part ["mpn"]+"  " +part["octopart_url"]);
            }*/

        }



        // -- your API key -- (https://octopart.com/api/register)
        private const string APIKEY = "57af648b";
    }



}
```

DebugConsole script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class DebugConsole : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject DebugGui = null;             // The GUI that will be duplicated
    public Vector3 defaultGuiPosition = new Vector3(0.01F, 0.98F, 0F);
    public Vector3 defaultGuiScale = new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 1F);
    public Color normal = Color.green;
    public Color warning = Color.yellow;
    public Color error = Color.red;
    public int maxMessages = 30;                   // The max number of messages displayed
    public float lineSpacing = 0.02F;              // The amount of space between lines
    public ArrayList messages = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList guis = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList colors = new ArrayList();
    public bool draggable = true;                  // Can the output be dragged around at runtime by default? 
    public bool visible = true;                    // Does output show on screen by default or do we have to enable it with code? 
    public bool pixelCorrect = false; // set to be pixel Correct linespacing
    public static bool isVisible
    {                                      
        get
        {
            return DebugConsole.instance.visible;
        }

        set
        {
            DebugConsole.instance.visible = value;
            if (value == true)
            {
                DebugConsole.instance.Display();
            }
            else if (value == false)
            {
                DebugConsole.instance.ClearScreen();
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool isDraggable
    {                                      
        get
        {
            return DebugConsole.instance.draggable;
        }

        set
        {
            DebugConsole.instance.draggable = value;

        }
    }


    private static DebugConsole s_Instance = null;   // Our instance to allow this script to be called without a direct connection.
    public static DebugConsole instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (s_Instance == null)
            {
                s_Instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof(DebugConsole)) as DebugConsole;
                if (s_Instance == null)
                {
                    GameObject console = new GameObject();
                    console.AddComponent<DebugConsole>();
                    console.name = "DebugConsoleController";
                    s_Instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof(DebugConsole)) as DebugConsole;
                    DebugConsole.instance.InitGuis();
                }

            }

            return s_Instance;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        s_Instance = this;
        InitGuis();

    }

    protected bool guisCreated = false;
    protected float screenHeight =-1;
    public void InitGuis()
    {
        float usedLineSpacing = lineSpacing;
        screenHeight = Screen.height;
        if(pixelCorrect)
            usedLineSpacing = 1.0F / screenHeight * usedLineSpacing;  

        if (guisCreated == false)
        {
            if (DebugGui == null)  // If an external GUIText is not set, provide the default GUIText
            {
                DebugGui = new GameObject();
                DebugGui.AddComponent<GUIText>();
                DebugGui.name = "DebugGUI(0)";
                DebugGui.transform.position = defaultGuiPosition;
                DebugGui.transform.localScale = defaultGuiScale;
            }

            // Create our GUI objects to our maxMessages count
            Vector3 position = DebugGui.transform.position;
            guis.Add(DebugGui);
            int x = 1;

            while (x < maxMessages)
            {
                position.y -= usedLineSpacing;
                GameObject clone = null;
                clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(DebugGui, position, transform.rotation);
                clone.name = string.Format("DebugGUI({0})", x);
                guis.Add(clone);
                position = clone.transform.position;
                x += 1;
            }

            x = 0;
            while (x < guis.Count)
            {
                GameObject temp = (GameObject)guis[x];
                temp.transform.parent = DebugGui.transform;
                x++;
            }
            guisCreated = true;
        } else {
            // we're called on a screensize change, so fiddle with sizes
            Vector3 position = DebugGui.transform.position;
            for(int x=0;x < guis.Count; x++)
            {
                position.y -= usedLineSpacing;
                GameObject temp = (GameObject)guis[x];
                temp.transform.position= position;
            }       
        }
    }



    bool connectedToMouse = false;  
    void Update()
    {
        // If we are visible and the screenHeight has changed, reset linespacing
        if (visible == true && screenHeight != Screen.height)
        {
            InitGuis();
        }
        if (draggable == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                if (connectedToMouse == false && DebugGui.GetComponent<GUIText>().HitTest((Vector3)Input.mousePosition) == true)
                {
                    connectedToMouse = true;
                }
                else if (connectedToMouse == true)
                {
                    connectedToMouse = false;
                }

            }

            if (connectedToMouse == true)
            {
                float posX = DebugGui.transform.position.x;
                float posY = DebugGui.transform.position.y;
                posX = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width;
                posY = Input.mousePosition.y / Screen.height;
                DebugGui.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, 0F);
            }
        }

    }
    //+++++++++ INTERFACE FUNCTIONS ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    public static void Log(string message, string color)
    {
        DebugConsole.instance.AddMessage(message, color);

    }
    //++++ OVERLOAD ++++
    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        DebugConsole.instance.AddMessage(message);
    }

    public static void Clear()
    {
        DebugConsole.instance.ClearMessages();
    }
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


    //---------- void AddMesage(string message, string color) ------
    //Adds a mesage to the list
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    public void AddMessage(string message, string color)
    {
        messages.Add(message);
        colors.Add(color);
        Display();
    }
    //++++++++++ OVERLOAD for AddMessage ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    // Overloads AddMessage to only require one argument(message)
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    public void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        messages.Add(message);
        colors.Add("normal");
        Display();
    }


    //----------- void ClearMessages() ------------------------------
    // Clears the messages from the screen and the lists
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    public void ClearMessages()
    {
        messages.Clear();
        colors.Clear();
        ClearScreen();
    }


    //-------- void ClearScreen() ----------------------------------
    // Clears all output from all GUI objects
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    void ClearScreen()
    {
        if (guis.Count < maxMessages)
        {
            //do nothing as we haven't created our guis yet
        }
        else
        {
            int x = 0;
            while (x < guis.Count)
            {
                GameObject gui = (GameObject)guis[x];   
                gui.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = "";
                //increment and loop
                x += 1;
            }
        }
    }   


    //---------- void Prune() ---------------------------------------
    // Prunes the array to fit within the maxMessages limit
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    void Prune()
    {
        int diff;
        if (messages.Count > maxMessages)
        {
            if (messages.Count <= 0)
            {
                diff = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                diff = messages.Count - maxMessages;
            }
            messages.RemoveRange(0, (int)diff);
            colors.RemoveRange(0, (int)diff);
        }

    }

    //---------- void Display() -------------------------------------
    // Displays the list and handles coloring
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    void Display()
    {
        //check if we are set to display
        if (visible == false)
        {
            ClearScreen();
        }
        else if (visible == true)
        {


            if (messages.Count > maxMessages)
            {
                Prune();
            }

            // Carry on with display
            int x = 0;
            if (guis.Count < maxMessages)
            {
                //do nothing as we havent created our guis yet
            }
            else
            {
                while (x < messages.Count)
                {
                    GameObject gui = (GameObject)guis[x];   

                    //set our color
                    switch ((string)colors[x])
                    {
                    case "normal": gui.GetComponent<GUIText>().material.color = normal;
                        break;
                    case "warning": gui.GetComponent<GUIText>().material.color = warning;
                        break;
                    case "error": gui.GetComponent<GUIText>().material.color = error;
                        break;
                    }

                    //now set the text for this element
                    gui.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = (string)messages[x];

                    //increment and loop
                    x += 1;
                }
            }

        }
    }


}// End DebugConsole Class
```

[image: Window where I want the gui text to appear]

[image: Hierarchy]

Comment: GUIText is a legacy component. Use the [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) component! The one I used in my answer from your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087540/print-json-to-screen-as-a-block-of-text-in-unity) question

Comment: @Programmer , so i decided to use just one api. So i tried what you said , I get this --- Look rotation viewing vector is zero. Almost a hundred times.I added my code , if you could ,please do take a look

Comment: The screenshot and code shows you are still using GUIText. Do you not understand what I am saying? Use the Text component not GUIText.

Comment: I ve irritated the only soul helping me. Okay Im sorry. It works.Thanks